# Using an existing array in another class

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Let's change the way I am asking the question. For constructing an object in a class, we can also use some other variables. Consider this example:

```
public class Foo {
    int X1;
    int X2;
    public Foo(int a) {
        int[] array=new int[4];
        // ...
    }
}
```

If we create 2 objects of this class, we will have 2 variables per object and totally the memory will be occupied for 4 integer variables. My concern is the memory dedicated to the integer array defined inside the constructor. How the memory will be assigned when creating several objects?

Thanks,

Comment: No code to show? ... I guess Probrably what you want is to define a constant array in a neutral class (i.e. some class to contain the constant used by your program an nothing else). But without code this is just a guess.

Comment: If you won't copy the array and just pass the reference, then the only overhead will be the reference(usually 4 bytes) to that array in the second class

Comment: It is always good practice, on StackOverflow, to include a short, self-contained, compilable example.

That being said, what are you using your array for?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes.  If you create an array in the `main` method of one class, then you create the same array *again* in the constructor of another class, then there will be two copies of that array in memory.  More importantly, if you later modify one copy, the other copy will not be modified.

The best way to solve your problem is to pass the array into the constructor as a parameter.  Then, you'll be able to access (and even modify) elements of the original array.  For example:

```
public class Driver{
    public static void Main(String[] args){
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
        CustomObject otherObject = new CustomObject(array);
    }
}

//And, in a different file....
public class CustomObject{
    public CustomObject(int[] array){
        int x = array[0];
        //etc..
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have two references to the same object there won't be any useless memory usage.
For better understand how it works, look at the [difference between stack and heap memory in Java](http://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-memory-vs-stack-memory-difference)

(Basically, your array in main method and the array defined in the class's constructor point to the same memory area)

Comment: *Basically, your array in main method and the array defined in the class's constructor point to the same memory area* is wrong.  If an array is **defined** in the main method, and also **defined** in the class's constructor, then it is **defined** twice, and thus points to two different memory locations.  If, however, a **reference** to the original array was passed, then yes, they refer to the same memory area.

Comment: sorry for the semantics, dude... However the point is still the same: there's no waste of memory